# В чем разница между git clone в Intellige IDEA и git clone в cmd: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, github

Здравствуйте.

Windows 10, Git-2.17.0-64-bit, GCMW-1.15.2

У меня есть

[проект на github](https://github.com/drno-reg/um_open.git)

Я с ним до недавнего времени работал через Intellige IDEA. (update, commit и т.д.)

Недавно решил сделать простой

```
git clone https://github.com/drno-reg/um_open.git GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true
```

и получил ошибку SSL:

```
Cloning into 'GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/drno-reg/um_open.git/': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

p.s.
пытался следовать рекомендациям

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944875/sourcetree-error1407742essl-routinesssl23-get-server-hellotlsv1-alert-protoc

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/201457/unable-to-connect-to-github-due-to-tls-12-only-cha.html

ничего не помогло....

Comment: А зачем вам `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true`? Оно вам точно нужно? И если без него - то какая-то ошибка остаётся?

Comment: пытался отключить проверку ssl сертификата

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/201457/unable-to-connect-to-github-due-to-tls-12-only-cha.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это нужно разово установить переменную, то надо набрать команду так

`GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone https://github.com/drno-reg/um_open.git`

Если же хочется, чтобы настройка действовала всегда, то лучше добавить её в конфигурацию гита:

`git config --local http.sslVerify false`

Но эта настройка будет действовать только в текущем репозитории. Как работать с глобальными/локальными конфигами можно посмотреть [на этом видео](https://youtu.be/6k8pNsCLtFI)

Comment: При выполнении команды 1. Возвращается ошибка 'GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

В общем до вчерашнего дня эта разница была, видимо все-таки Intelige IDEA что-то добавляла от себя.
НО после 10-очереди сноса git клиента эта ошибки стала воспроизводиться и в IDEA.

После команда определения глобального параметра решила проблему:

```
git config --global --add http.sslVersion tlsv1.2
```